# Need to add additional line chart on column chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to add new line chart on column chart in highcharts

[line chart http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9335/unh.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9335/unh.png)

here i want to add additional green line chart on exiting one.

Answer (score 0):

here it is. you can right click and save it.

[image]

Comment: no, my requirement is to add adhditional line chart on exiting column chart

Answer (score 0):

Use `chart.addSeries(options)`, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()